# Safari CSS media query combined with OR not workign

Tags: css, safari, media-queries, mobile-safari

Why is this not working Safari Browser? The rules inside that block are not firing.

```
@media(max-width:1280px) OR (max-height:1080px) {

}
```

When i make two blocks, one with max-width: 1280 and one with max-height:1080 then it's working. Does Safari Browser does not support OR combination in Media Queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "or" media query is a comma-separated statement, like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px), (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Example from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-css-media-queries/#aa-or)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)  has good resources too

Comment: Oh thanks :D thought it was some Safari issue because all other browser seems to support OR